# Navigate Screens in Flows

Tags: lightning, visual-workflow, aura, lightning-flow-builder

I understand that I can use the following to be able to navigate to the Next Screen in a flow:

```
  var navigate = component.get("v.navigateFlow");
  navigate("NEXT");
```

My concern is that I want to go next twice. I have tried the below but it is not working:

```
 var navigate = component.get("v.navigateFlow");
 navigate("NEXT");
 navigate("NEXT");
```

Has anyone experienced something like this before?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would suggest you provide some details on the component and how it is being utilized in the lightning flow. With the given details, I assume that you have used a component (_that implements `lightning:availableForFlowScreens` interface_) and placed it a screen within the flow. I probably need to try this out at my end, but my best guess it that after the first `navigate("NEXT")` code execution, the flow has moved out from context of the current component over to the next screen (_which may have another component_). So, the 2nd `navigate("NEXT")` might be pointless?

Comment: @arut You are correct in your assumption. The second navigate("NEXT") is pointless. I need to be able to take users to a specific screen. I have a form and users want to be able to start the form where they left off, I store the stage and know which screen this is. The only way I have found to do this at the moment is by using $Flow.ActiveStages $Flow.CurrentStage which doesn't work properly (see comment I left on post by Boris Gichev).

Comment: (1) Are you unable to conditionally code `navigate("NEXT")` in all the aura components until you reach the expected screen? I'm sure this should be possible. And, How are you capturing the stage (or screen) where the user previously left? (2) Regarding the comment you left on BorisGichev's post, what do you mean by "the user won't be able to go back to the first screen as previous button won't be visible"? I was able to see the previous button in my test screen flow. (3) Could you add some relevant details using which I could replicate the flow?

Comment: I have a picklist on an object which contains all the screens of the flow. Once a user gets to a particular screen an update element will update this picklist, this is how I will know the last position of the user. Lets say the user exits the flow in screen 3.. I have a button which calls an aura component which then invokes the flow. When user clicks on this button I need all data user previously entered to be visible on previous screens and user to be able to start directly where they left off. Prob is if I take them to screen 3 directly using a decision, this won't allow me to go previous

Answer (score 1):

My best suggestion is to utilize $Flow.ActiveStages $Flow.CurrentStage
inside the flow instead doing this from the JS of the lightning component(assuming you are trying to do that).

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=flow_ref_resources_stage_examples_subflow.htm&type=5

Or you can see if those global stage variables are accessible in the JS controller also.
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=flow_ref_resources_system_variables.htm&type=5

Comment: The problem with using CurrentStage is the following:

Stage 1 = first screen,
Stage 2 = second screen,
Stage 3 = third screen.

On start of the flow if I set the Current Stage to "Stage 2" then the flow will load the second screen and the user won't be able to go back to the first screen as previous button won't be visible. Let's say the user was filling a form and existed the flow on the second screen - I am able to take them back to the second screen but they can't click previous anymore

Comment: Above the "existed" should be "left"***